Live refresh with lerna
So I have a project with 2 packages bundled using Lerna. I need to have a live refresh whenever any changes are detected. But here is the catch. The first package is an API run continuously. The second one is a typescript package with some additional classes. and whenever changes are detected in a classes package it needs to be transpiled, and the API package needs to replace the package inside node_modules and refresh itself
I have tried using Lerna scripts but they are not handling continuous changes

use Lerna watch, it's supported by both Lerna and Lerna-Lite but their implementation is different Lerna uses Nx to watch while Lerna-Lite uses chokidar.
